# Error #1006: gotoAndStop is not a function

Tags: actionscript-3

This is driving me insane trying to figure this out because I know it's simple.

I have the following code in the last frame of a movie clip on the timeline. When the framehead hits the last frame of the mc, i want to go back to the frame "photoIntro" on the main timeline.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, goBackToTimeline);

function goBackToTimeline(event:Event):void
 {
 Object(this.parent).gotoAndStop("photoIntro");
 }
```

The output error I keep getting is:

TypeError: Error #1006: gotoAndStop is not a function.
 at PandU_EmergingIssuesKiosk_v1c_fla::logoAnimationMO V_1/goBackToTimeline().

Help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you casting it as a Object ? Why not MovieClip?

```
MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndStop("photoIntro");
```

As the commenter noted, the cast isn't really needed at all and you could just use :

`parent.gotoAndStop("photoIntro");`

Comment: Or casting it at all for that matter.

Comment: Yeah, very true. `parent.gotoAndStop("photoIntro");` should work fine.